Como compartir base de datos en django para usuarios
Tengo Varios proyectos para desplegar todos en django, los cuales me quiero compartir la base de datos (MySQL) de los usuarios para que todos puedan autenticarse con las mismas credenciales en los varios proyectos. Mi idea es compartir solo la tabla de usuarios, ya que también quisiera que tengan su propia base de datos para cada proyecto.
Me gustaria saber si existe una posibilidad de realizar una configuración. Y si es viable realizar esto y de ser asi por donde empezar.
Hablo de la configuración de Django para acceder a 2 BD distintas, ya que el modelo de usuario quiero que este en una Base de Datos distinta a los demás modelos, para que ese modelo sea compartido con los demás proyectos. En este caso si tiene que ver el lenguaje ya que la configuración se la debe hacer en Django.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No se que tiene que ver el lenguaje (en este caso, nada, tu problema es db y como acceder a ella). a que te referis con compartir? podrias poner un ejemplo?

Hablo de la configuración de Django para acceder a 2 BD distintas, ya que el modelo de usuario quiero que este en una Base de Datos distinta a los demás modelos, para que ese modelo sea compartido con los demás proyectos. En este caso si tiene que ver el lenguaje ya que la configuración  se la debe hacer en Django.

Ah perfecto.. eso no quedaba claro en la pregunta..

Investigando en la documentación de django, la configuración se detalla en el siguiente link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/5.0/topics/db/multi-db/.
Actualmente en este ejemplo aclara:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/5.0/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example
Que podemos tener varias BD, pero django no asegura poder realizar las relaciones entre ellas, es decir que si tenes un modelo (en Base de datos 1) que se relaciona con otro modelo (en Base de datos 2) no podrás realizar las relaciones  entre esos modelos
